# Referer header when linking to a non-SSL site, from an SSL site

Tags: security, https

Section 15.1.3 in RFC 2616 states:

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol

However, I know many browsers have bugs and don't always follow spec, plus it only says SHOULD NOT, instead of MUST NOT. So my question is therefore:

1) Is there any browser (past, present, or beta) that breaks spec and DOES send the referer header when a request is made from a secure site
2) Are there any tools, browser plugins, or any way at all to modify a browser to break spec and send the referer header when making such a request
3) Is there any official sounding source, or load of information from security pros about this problem anywhere on the web that I can look at.

For a bit of background, this is part of a security review of my app which runs over SSL, and the spec is that no referer information should be sent to 3rd party sites. My testing has found no browser that will send the referer header in this scenario, but I would like to be very confident that I'm right.

Comment: As part of your security review, I'd suggest that you should never really assume that the clients that are ultimately not under your control will do what they're supposed to do. Even if there was a "MUST NOT" in the spec, you wouldn't be able to guarantee, as a web app provider, that no user-agent would ever send this referrer header. It's generally more about risk-assessment regarding which browsers your target users will use: if needed, warn them they might leak information if they use a browser you haven't tested (although I'd think the probability is quite low).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in Firefox, if the 3rd-party site is over HTTPS, the referer header will be sent, according to the [`network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer) option (accessible via `about:config` in the address bar).